# Stream Json with python localy

Tags: python, json, streaming, gephi

I would like to stream a JSON locally with python (so as another program read it). Is there any package that streams in a clean way the json in a local address? (as I used print but instead of the terminal, a local url).

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean "stream json"?

Comment: @JoranBeasley I believe he is referring to a way to make a JSON available to multiple process on the machine.

Comment: if you have a file open for reading other processes should be able to open it fine ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley ... or through a [socket](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html)?

Comment: I have a listener (?) in my Gephi application ready to get information as json, so if I am correct I need to push the json on a local address  in order the listener get the data. Maybe creating a small local server?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but as a workaround to letting javascript access my local json, I just kind of embed my json inside a javascript and then include that javascript in my web page.

Comment: maybe this is what your looking for? http://docs.paasmaker.org/user-gettingstarted.html .... I dunno its hard to tell what you want to do ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import SocketServer
import json

class Server(SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True

class Handler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.request.sendall(json.dumps({'id':'3000'}))  # your JSON

server = Server(('127.0.0.1', 50009), Handler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Test with:

```
~  ᐅ curl 127.0.0.1:50009
{"id": 3000}
```